# Components still disjointedly loading despite using React Suspense

Tags: reactjs, react-suspense

The behavior I'm trying to fix:
[image]

Unless I'm misunderstanding something, Suspense should be good to use here. How I implemented it in my app.js

```
const ChatContainer = React.lazy(() => import('./components/ChatContainer'))

<Router>
    <Routes>
        <Route>
            <Route element={<RequireAuth/>}>
                <Route path="chat" element={
                    <Suspense fallback={<ChatBackground><BeatLoader/></ChatBackground>}>
                        <ChatContainer/>
                    </Suspense>
                }/>
                <Route path="profile" element={<Profile/>}/>
                <Route path="signout" element={<SignOut/>}/>
            </Route>
            <Route path="signup" element={<SignUp/>}/>
            <Route path="signin" element={<SignIn/>}/>
            <Route path="/" element={<SignIn/>}/>
        </Route>
    </Routes>
</Router>
```

The ChatContainer component contains all the other components in the app except the background. What am I missing here?

Comment: Does it contain left padding/margin?

Comment: What are you referring to?

Comment: Sorry, I meant to ask whether your fallback contain these.

Comment: ChatBackground doesn't and BeatLoader is a a pre-made component from react-spinners

Comment: Then you'll have the glitch, since react is replacing your fallback as soon as it can load your actual component. If the don't "look" the same, then you'll have this movement.

Comment: ChatBackground is also inside of ChatContainer but I tried moving it and putting it in app.js so that both BeatLoader and ChatContainer are wrapped in ChatBackground but no dice, it's still busted. Is that what you meant or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Maybe it's `ChatContainer` problem. If it renders the contacts with a delay.